# Why does weight paint looking bad?

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

It was fine on the low poly version of my model but then it started acting up when I turned on subdivision modifier the weight paint looks like swiss cheese. Is there a way to fix this?[image][image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/932561aeef314e9dbe14818fd3244823

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Looked at file.  It has something to do with your subdivision modifier.  TL;DR: don't worry about it, the weights are fine.  Should it be displaying this way?  Almost certainly not.  It's showing weights on unselectable verts created by the subdiv modifier, and those weights are inaccurate.  Especially considering that your subdiv is being evaluated after your armature (the weights on those virtual verts mean nothing.)  Probably a bug, possibly worth reporting, but it's not very meaningful.  Testing in 2.92 shows similar behavior but different.

Comment: If you report it as a bug, please link me; otherwise, I may report it myself.  Maybe not though, it's not a very important bug.

Comment: Thanks for the update so it's just a bug nothing to worry about? Then can you report it I'm not good at this technical stuff in fact this would be my first time.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's not a super-important bug, so you shouldn't feel bad about letting it be.  I'll think a bit about whether I think it's worth reporting (which will also give me some time to consider details to the problem.)

Comment: More examination.  Real answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh is bugged.  I can't tell you how it happened.  I can tell you that it *shouldn't* have happened.  So it's a bug with Blender.

Let's open a sidebar and enter weight paint, then select a particular vertex and look at its weights:

[image]

That's a bugged out vertex group, as apparent from its display.  But look more closely at the *list* of vertex groups that this vertex belongs to: there are two different entries for Mid2.L!  And 2 entries for Mid1.L, and for Mid3.L, and maybe for some other groups that I didn't notice.

This should never, ever happen.  No operation should ever cause this to happen.  Blender ought to have sanity checks to prevent it from happening, but apparently it doesn't.  Vertex groups have a unique ID, but just like anything else in Blender, they should also have a unique *name*, and so a lot of functions-- like interpolation of weights following subdivision-- rely on that name instead of that ID.  And when the names are there twice, for two different IDs, bad stuff happens.

So, bugged.  But there's good news!  So long as you're willing to lose/redo your weights, this is easily fixable:

1. In object mode, in properties/object data/vertex groups, click on the vertex group specials (the downward pointing arrow to the right of the list of groups) and select "delete all groups".

[image]

2. Reweight your mesh, probably by parenting it to your armature with automatic weights.

Now, even though I don't know why this happened, this most definitely is a bug with Blender.  I plan to submit a portion of this object as a bug report.  I've seen duplicated vertex groups like this before, and having an object where it exists is hopefully enough for Blender devs to understand that it *can* happen, that it causes bad things when it happens, and that it can be prevented.

I've filed a bug report related to this at https://developer.blender.org/T93087 .